# Automatic rewriting of dead links on Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, links

A website has been reorganized. Pages that used to be at URLs of the form `http://foo.example.com/bar/wibble` are now accessible only at `http://goo.example.com/baz/wibble` (i.e. there's a simple mechanical transformation between them).

There are about a thousand pages on `wikipedia.org` that link to this website — mostly references in many articles (the website hosts a number of articles that have authoritative information on a particular topic).

Is there an existing, working way of updating the links automatically? From what I know of Wikipedia, I'd expect this to be someone running a bot. Does someone operate such a bot? If not, is there such bot software that meets the approval of the Wikipedia community?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to solve this would be to use **AutoWikiBrowser**, a semi-automated MediaWiki editor. [Guidelines and instructions are available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser) (but may vary depending on which language version of Wikipedia you will be editing).